# Object reference null problem while using IUnitOfWorkManager with Tenant ID in Background Service class in Abp Framework

Tags: .net-core, abp

I need to create a Background Service and it’s purpose to do some job in the background. I am using **Abp Framework with .NET Core**. Here is my code.

```
public class TestJob : BackgroundService
    {
        private IConfiguration _configuration;
        private readonly UserManager _userManager;
        public readonly IRepository<User, long> _repositoryUser;
        private readonly IUnitOfWorkManager _unitOfWorkManager;

        public TestJob(
            IConfiguration configuration,
            UserManager userManager,
            IRepository<User, long> repositoryUser,
            IUnitOfWorkManager unitOfWorkManager)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
            _userManager = userManager;
            _repositoryUser = repositoryUser;
            _unitOfWorkManager = unitOfWorkManager;
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("=================================================");

                using (_unitOfWorkManager.Current.SetTenantId(1))
                {
                    using (var uow = _unitOfWorkManager.Begin())
                    {
                        var users = await _repositoryUser.GetAll().ToListAsync();

                        foreach (var user in users)
                        {
                            await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync(user.EmailAddress);
                        }
                        
                        var u = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync("219");                        

                        await uow.CompleteAsync();
                    }
                }

                await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
            }
        }        
    }
```

But I am getting the below error in this line **_unitOfWorkManager.Current.SetTenantId(1)**

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Can anyone give me suggestion how to fix the problem?

Comment: Are you sure this is ABP Framework `[abp]`, which doesn't ship `SetTenantID` method, and not ASP.NET Boilerplate `[aspnetboilerplate]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `Begin` a unit of work before `SetTenantID` on the (current) unit of work.

Change:

```cs
using (_unitOfWorkManager.Current.SetTenantId(1))
{
    using (var uow = _unitOfWorkManager.Begin())
```

to:

```cs
using (var uow = _unitOfWorkManager.Begin())
{
    using (_unitOfWorkManager.Current.SetTenantId(1))
```